# Design Palette for SWT

Tags: eclipse, swt

Is there a way to replicate the design palette from the Eclipse Visual Editor in an SWT application?

Comment: The screen capture link is stale, not available anymore. Also, next time [don't use URL shorteners](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136) and avoid linking directly to an image in someone else site. If you want to post a screen capture, StackOverflow supports uploading images to imgur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at **[GEF  Graphical Editing Framework](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/)** which would, on top of eclipse and SWT, provide some [palette resources](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.gef.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/gef/palette/package-summary.html).

An example of palette os found in this article [GEF with EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-EMF/gef-emf.html)

[image]

As said in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg05234.html):

> all the palette is just another graphical viewer which you can place in any viewpart pretty much.